# Sencha Touch Packaging to Android Error

Tags: android, sencha-touch, package, sencha-command

Im having trouble packaging my aplication to android using Sencha Cmd v3.0.0.250 in Windows.
I run the command `sencha package build packager.json` and gives me this error:

```
[ERR]       
Created directory C:\Users\Wesker\Desktop\Tiempo\src\com\sencha\Tiempo
Added file C:\Users\Wesker\Desktop\Tiempo\src\com\sencha\Tiempo\STActivity.java
Created directory C:\Users\Wesker\Desktop\Tiempo\res
Created directory C:\Users\Wesker\Desktop\Tiempo\bin
Created directory C:\Users\Wesker\Desktop\Tiempo\libs
Created directory C:\Users\Wesker\Desktop\Tiempo\res\values
Added file C:\Users\Wesker\Desktop\Tiempo\res\values\strings.xml
Created directory C:\Users\Wesker\Desktop\Tiempo\res\layout
Added file C:\Users\Wesker\Desktop\Tiempo\res\layout\main.xml
Added file C:\Users\Wesker\Desktop\Tiempo\AndroidManifest.xml
Added file C:\Users\Wesker\Desktop\Tiempo\build.xml
Added file C:\Users\Wesker\Desktop\Tiempo\proguard-project.txt
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
""C:/Android\tools\android" create project --target android-10 --name Tiempo --activity STActivity --path "C:/Users/Wesker/Desktop/Tiempo\/" --package com.sencha.Tiempo"
Could not run ant with error: 1
Failed to package application

[ERR]       stbuild exited with non-zero code : 7
```

Here is my json file:

```
{
"applicationName":"Tiempo",
"applicationId":"com.sencha.Tiempo",
"bundleSeedId":"KPXFEPZ6EF",
"versionString":"1.0",
"versionCode":"1",
"icon": {
    "57":"resources/icons/Icon.png",
    "72":"resources/icons/Icon~ipad.png",
    "114":"resources/icons/Icon@2x.png",
    "144":"resources/icons/Icon~ipad@2x.png"
},
"inputPath":"C:/Users/Wesker/Documents/Tiempo/app",
"outputPath":"C:/Users/Wesker/Desktop/Tiempo",
"configuration":"Debug",
"platform":"Android",
"deviceType":"Universal",
"certificatePath":"C:/Users/Wesker/Documents/Tiempo/keyTiempo.keystore",
"certificateAlias": "tiempo",
"certificatePassword":"123456",
"provisionProfile":"",
"sdkPath":"C:/Android",
"androidAPILevel":"10",
"permissions":[
    "INTERNET",
    "ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE",
    "CAMERA",
    "VIBRATE",
    "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
    "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
    "CALL_PHONE"
],
"orientations": [
    "portrait",
    "landscapeLeft",
    "landscapeRight",
    "portraitUpsideDown"
]
```

}

I dont know why its trying to execute C:\Program. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

I had to put all the tools out of the "Program Files" dir. Meaning I put android, sencha-cmd etc. on c:\, not in c:\Program(NOT_working_SPACE_here)Files.